# jsf2 + <managed-property> <property-name>

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, faces-config

I have a mapped bean in **faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>beanName</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>elements</property-name>
   <map-entries>
    <key-class>java.lang.String</key-class>
    <value-class>path.InputFormElementContainer</value-class>
   </map-entries>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>
```

The implementation in java is:

```
public class InputFormElementContainer implements List<InputFormElement>, Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4685106549564090233L;
    private List<InputFormElement> elements;

    //Empty Constructor
    public InputFormElementContainer() {
        elements = new ArrayList<InputFormElement>();
    }
    public List<InputFormElement> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
    public void setElements(List<InputFormElement> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error when I refresh my application:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: No se puede crear el bean administrado beanName.  Se han encontrado los problemas siguientes:
     - No existe la propiedad elements para el bean administrado beanName.
```

The translation to english could be: can not create the administrated beanName due to the following problem:  elemts property does not exist for beanName.

This problem came to me in the migration to JSF2. I was reading tutorials, but I could't figure out how to make this manage-bean propperly in JSF2. Could anybody help me??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/ this page could be very useful, but it is not include my case in partocular

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong

```
<managed-bean-name>beanName</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>elements</property-name>
```

here jsf will search for getters/setters of the field `elements` in [java.util.HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which doesn't exist, and so the error

Comment: But in the way that is mapped, I want to specify that beanName is a hashMap<Sring, InputFormElementContainer>. Am I doing it wrong??

Comment: I don't want to specify elements as a HashMap, but I need beanName to  be hashMap<String, InputFormElementContainer>. How could I write the elements type to be not a HashMap?? Is it different way now in JSF2 than it was before?? In JSF1 this same code was working

Comment: I mean, how could I declare elements as List<InputFormElement> (as in backend)

Comment: still its unclear to me *but I need beanName to be hashMap<String, InputFormElementContainer>.*

Comment: beanName ->  hashMap<String, InputFormElementContainer> elements -> List<InputFormElement>, which is a field inside InputFormElementContainer. How could I manage this in faces-config?? Thansk, and sorry for me english

Answer (score 0):

You have two options depending of how you want to model your class InputFormElementContainer

If you need 'elements' to be a List:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>beanName</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>elements</property-name>
    <property-class>java.util.ArrayList</property-class>
    <list-entries>
      <value-class>path.InputFormElementContainer</value-class>
      <value>...</value
      ...
    </list-entries>
  </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Or if you need 'elements' property to be a Map:

```
<managed-bean>
      <managed-bean-name>beanName</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
      <managed-property>
        <property-name>elements</property-name>
        <property-class>java.util.HashMap</property-class>
        <map-entries>
          <key-class>java.lang.String</key-class>
          <value-class>path.InputFormElementContainer</value-class>
          <map-entry>
            <key></key>
            <value></value>
          </map-entry>
        </map-entries>
      </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
```